# Coming round to dinner

Tags: idiom-meaning

''In fact, she is **coming round to dinner** this evening''

I've done my research on the web, but I can't find its meaning. My question is, why did they use this idiom instead of just going to dinner? Is/are there any more specific things to do besides from just going... thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, why did they use this idiom instead of just going to
>   dinner?

The difference is a change in meaning. If the statement read:

> In fact, she is going to dinner this evening

The meaning would be that the *she* was going to dinner, going implies travel, so the meaning here is that *she* is going to dinner somewhere, but the place has not been articulated in the statement.

Conversely:

Come[ing] around, in the context of the sentence means:

> To visit someone in their home:
>   -- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-round)

So the place of the dinner has been specified.

The meaning here is that *she* is going to the house of the narrator for dinner this evening.